# Making a for loop read 2 lines of a text file at a time

Tags: regex, variables, batch-file, for-loop, replace

I have a set of folders with a txt file of the same name in each one. They're path is

```
C:\Test\Salford_xxx\MenuSettings.txt
C:\Test\Salford_xxx\MenuSettings.txt
C:\Test\Salford_xxx\MenuSettings.txt
```

Where xxx is a random 3 digit number. I want the 1st line of each of these files to be changed using a text file called input.txt, which has the path and the line thats replacing the 1st line of each file. It looks like this.

```
C:\TEST\SALFORD_001\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing 1"
C:\TEST\SALFORD_011\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing 2"
C:\TEST\SALFORD_345\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing  3"
C:\TEST\SALFORD_761\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing 4"
C:\TEST\SALFORD_768\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing 5"
C:\TEST\SALFORD_999\MENUSETTINGS.TXT
AppName: "This needs replacing 6"
```

I've written a for loop that puts the path and the replacement in variables, which works:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /R /I "Salford" Input.txt') do (set "FilePath=%%a" echo %FilePath%)
for /F "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /R /I "AppName" Input.txt') do (set "NewName=%%b" echo %NewName%)
```

AppName is a word that is always in the first line, so that is used to search.
Here is the script for replacing the line of each file.

```
set "search=Appname"
set "replace=%NewName%"
set "newfile=NewOutput.txt"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%FilePath%) do (
set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
move "%newfile%" "%FilePath%"
```

However the loop continues to the last item in the Salford_999 folder and just edits that file. How can i make this read the first 2 lines of input.txt, make the replacement and then loop to the next two lines and so on?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how your problem is reading two lines of input.txt.  I see no code that makes sure you are only trying to edit MENUSETTINGS.txt.  That seems to be what your problem is.

Comment: The input.txt file has MenuSettings.txt reference in it, thats all thats needed surely? It is the only text file in each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how your code use your specifications. For example, your "for loop that puts the path in a variable" assign all paths *to the same variable*, so when the for ends, the variable have the *last value*. Also, I don't understand where the "AppName" string literal is taken from when it is used in the `findstr` in the second for. Finally, what happen if there is a file that have not its corresponding line in input.txt file?

A different approach is to process the input.txt file as a series of odd/even lines, and then process each one of the files described in odd lines; this may lead to a simpler solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process odd and even lines from input.txt file:
set "FilePath="
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined FilePath (  rem Odd line...
      rem Assign each odd line to "FilePath" variable
      set "FilePath=%%a"
   ) else (  rem Even line...
      rem Process this file, if it exists
      if exist "!FilePath!" (
         rem Block to enclose output to new file
         > newfile (
            rem The first line in new file is this even line in input.txt file
            echo %%a
            rem Copy all lines from this file, excepting the first one
            more +1 "!FilePath!"
         )
         move /Y newfile "!FilePath!"
      )
      set "FilePath="
   )
)
```

Comment: OK let me be clear about the AppName side of things. The old MenuSettings files have the line `AppName: "http://example1.com"` in them. So the "search" variable looks  for AppName in the old MenuSettings.txt files and replaces it with contents of the "Newname" variable from input.txt.

Comment: Ok. This means that `AppName: ` string is constant and just serve to identify odd lines, right? Did you tested my code? It will insert _whole_ odd lines in first line of the *.txt files, so you must remove the `AppName: ` and quotes from odd lines... Do you want I modify my code in order to process odd lines as they are now?